# How to use make_zoned from c++ date library?

Tags: c++, time, c++20, c++-chrono

I'm trying to use the date (https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) library to convert a data/time string into date/time belonging to a specific time zone.

I'm using this:

```
std::string t = "2024-01-02T14:42:27";
std::stringstream str(t);
std::chrono::time_point< std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::seconds > src_timestamp;
date::from_stream( str, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", result );
const auto src_tz = locate_zone(std::string("CET"));
auto zoned_src_timestamp = make_zoned(src_tz, src_timestamp);
std::cout << zoned_src_timestamp.get_local_time() << " TZ\n";
```

When I print zoned_src_timestamp.get_local_time() I expect to see my local time, but I get "2024-01-02 15:42:27" instead. This is not the local time that I'm expecting.

I'm trying to parse a date/time string into a time_point and use it with a timezone to have a local time that I can convert into a different timezone.

Comment: https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#make_zoned

Comment: This doesn't compile for me.  Where is `result` declared?

Comment: @NicolBolas:  How do you know this question is C++20-specific?  My date lib is targeted at C++11/14/17.

Comment: @HowardHinnant: Because it used the tag `c++-chrono` and only C++20's version of this library component has time zone features.

Comment: `c++-chrono` refers to C++11 and forward.  And this question does not mention C++20's time zone features.  It only mentions the pre-standard time zone features from https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date.  The last paragraph in my answer addresses this issue.  The `c++20` tag is only appropriate here if the OP says he is using, or wants to use C++20, or the C++20 chrono time zone features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to parse a date/time string into a time_point and use it with a timezone to have a local time that I can convert into a different timezone.

```
std::string t = "2024-01-02T14:42:27";
std::stringstream str(t);
```

So far so good.  But I'm interpreting "use it with a timezone" to mean, "parse the time as local time in a timezone", namely "CET".  To do this the type of `src_timestamp` must be a `local_time` instantiation as opposed to a `sys_time` instantiation.

`sys_time` is that family of `time_point` based on `system_clock` and always means [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).  `local_time` represents a local time that has yet to be paired with a specific `time_zone`.  There is a specific type alias for seconds-precision called `local_seconds` that can be handy to use:

```
date::local_seconds src_timestamp;
```

If you prefer another precision, say `milliseconds`, then that is:

```
date::local_time<std::chrono::millliseconds> src_timestamp;
```

Then do the parse with the `local_time`:

```
date::from_stream( str, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", src_timestamp );
```

If you print this back out, you'll get exactly the same time.  Now use it to create a `zoned_time` with the desired `time_zone`.  You can use either a `time_zone const*` or a string to specify the `time_zone`:

```
auto zoned_src_timestamp = date::zoned_time("CET", src_timestamp);
```

This assumes C++17 or higher.  `make_zoned` is convenient with C++11/14 as it works around the lack of [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction).

The construction of `zoned_src_timestamp` creates a pair data structure of `{time_zone const*, sys_time}`.  The `sys_time` is computed at construction by using the `time_zone const*` to convert the `local_time` to `sys_time`.  If you ask this object for the local time: `zoned_src_timestamp.get_local_time()` then it will just convert the `sys_time` back to the `local_time` you used to construct it with.

One can also construct a `zoned_time` with a `sys_time`, in which case the conversion from local is avoided at construction time, and the `sys_time` is simply stored.

One can also construct a `zoned_time` with *another* `zoned_time`.  I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
auto zoned_local_timestamp = date::zoned_time{date::current_zone(),
                                              zoned_src_timestamp};
```

This uses `current_zone()` as the `time_zone`, and `zoned_src_timestamp` as the "time stamp".

- `current_zone()` simply returns a `time_zone const*` to your computer's currently set local time zone.
- Construction with `zoned_src_timestamp` uses its `sys_time` to construct the new `zoned_time`, so that both `zoned_time` represent the same instant in time, though in (potentially) different timezones.  I.e. they have the same UTC time, but different local times.

Then you can get the local time out of `zoned_local_timestamp`:

```
std::cout << zoned_local_timestamp.get_local_time() << " TZ\n";
```

`zoned_time` is meant to simply be a convenience wrapper.  You can also work directly with `time_zone` to accomplish the same thing:

```
std::string t = "2024-01-02T14:42:27";
std::stringstream str(t);
date::local_seconds src_timestamp;
date::from_stream( str, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", src_timestamp );
auto utc_timestamp = date::locate_zone("CET")->to_sys(src_timestamp);
auto local_timestamp = date::current_zone()->to_local(utc_timestamp);
std::cout << local_timestamp << " TZ\n";
```

`zoned_time` becomes much more convenient when you want to format with UTC offsets or time zone abbreviations as the `zoned_time` collects everything there is to know about a `time_zone`/`local_time` combination into a single object.

`zoned_time` would also be more convenient in generic code where the "time stamp" could be either `sys_time` or `local_time`.

Finally, all of this is now part of C++20.  Implementations are still coming on line.  MSVC has it.  gcc-14 has it, with partial implementations in earlier versions.  LLVM has partial implementations.  If you are lucky enough to be working with a C++20 implementation, prefer that over `date`.  Everything will be in `namespace std::chrono` instead of `namespace date`.

Comment: Thanks. This looks more or less like that solution that I came up with myself. While I do appreciate that you wrote the library, I find the interface hard to understand. It might be that the use case that I'm trying to solve is different from the use cases documented in the library documentation.

Perhaps you should ask people for example code and attach it in the docs thus making it easier to understand? :) I know that there are some examples, but this wasn't adequate for me.

Comment: Also I'm using GCC (with C++20 support enabled) which doesn't have all the required features that I need and thus ended with using your library.

Comment: Here are a list of examples contributed by both myself and others: https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/wiki/Examples-and-Recipes

Comment: Shit. I didn't find that using Google. :(